Question from Born, Optics, p. 188 about system of two thin lenses
Max Born, in Optics at p. 188, says that given (1): $\frac{1}{f}=\frac{1}{f_1}+\frac{1}{f_2}-\frac{d}{f_1f_2}$, in which $f$ is the focal distance of a system consisting of two thin lenses with focal lengths respectively $f_1,f_2$, and distance between lenses $d$, if we have (2):
$$\frac{\delta f_1}{f_1^2} + \frac{\delta f_2}{f_2^2}- \frac{d}{f_1f_2}\left(\frac{\delta f_1}{f_1}+\frac{\delta f_2}{f_2}\right)=0 ,$$
"[i]t is seen that $\delta f = 0..."$
It is not seen by me. I replaced $f$ by $f+\delta f$ (etc.) in (1) (not shown), and then by getting a common denominator in (2) of $f_1^2f_2^2$ found (3):
$$ f_2^2\delta f_1+f_1^2\delta f_2 = d~(f2\delta f_1+f_1\delta f_2).$$
Solving for $d$ in (3), I put that in (1). This did not seem to give the desired result. My only intuition is that we should finally have something like (1) with additional terms on each side, and equating the additional terms would give $\delta f = 0.$
Insights or hint appreciated.
